# Rails uninitialized constant - when local but not in production on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out what would have changed to make this stop working.  It even works as it should on another dev laptop.

uninitialized constant Context::User::User

```
class Context::User

  def self.find_by_email(email)
    return nil if email.blank?
    User.find_by("LOWER(email) = ?", email.downcase.strip)
  end
end
```

Comment: try this `::User.find_by...` the `::` will look for the top class definition for `User`

Comment: @mr_sudaca perfect thank you that works